# How to force rotate dialog fragment?

Tags: android, dialog, rotation

How to rotate a dialog fragment 90 or 180 degrees if the activity screen orientation is locked?

**Activity** declared in manifest:

```
<activity
   ...
   android:screenOritentation="landscape" />
```

**Dialog** fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends DialogFragment{
   // stuff
}
```

I've rotated the dialog's layout using NineOldAndroid library. It is working as I expected if I rotate to 180 degree, however if I rotate to 90 degree, the layout is not visible entirely.

I am trying to rotate the entire dialog (not only the layout), inclusive buttons, title, everything, but I couldn't figured out how to to that.

Answer (score 3):

Main idea that You can try use some flags of [ActivityInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE) on methods onStart() and onStop() at DialogFragment.

For example for DialogFragment you can fix some orientation on onStart() method:

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    // lock screen;
    DisplayTools.Orientation orientation = DisplayTools.getDisplatOrientation(getActivity());
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(orientation == DisplayTools.Orientation.LANDSCAPE
                ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE
                : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
}
```

(this use something flags from [ActivityInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE))

And restore orientation on onStop() method:

```
@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    // unlock screen;
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
}
```

(on your particular case you must use ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE instead ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED at onStop() method)

Where

```
public class DisplayTools
{
    static public Point getDisplaySize(Context context)
    {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        return size;
    }

    static public Orientation getDisplatOrientation(Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity != null)
        {
            int orientation = activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            {
                return Orientation.LANDSCAPE;
            }
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
            {
                return Orientation.PORTRAIT;
            }
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED)
            {
                return Orientation.UNDEFINED;
            }
        }
        return Orientation.UNKNOWN;
    }

    public static enum Orientation
    {
        UNKNOWN(-1),
        UNDEFINED(0),
        PORTRAIT(1),
        LANDSCAPE(2);

        private int tag;

        Orientation(int i)
        {
            this.tag = i;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you understand main idea!

Comment: The problem with this is that the activity is recreated

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to inflate a specific layout for the dialog by the current orientation. In my app, the activity is locked to landscape, however, if I turn the device to portrait I am showing a specific layout without recreating the activity.

**Note:** It is not working with an already opened dialog. The dialog is not rotated when the device is rotated. It is rotated only at creation at the dialog.

Your activity:

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity
{
    private boolean isPortrait = false;
    private boolean isFlip = false;

    private OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        // stuff

        setUpOrientationListener();
    }

    // Register device to detected orientation change
    private void setUpOrientationListener()
    {
            orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)
            {
                @Override
                public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation)
                {
                    // Device is in portrait
                    if (orientation > 320 || orientation < 45)
                    {
                        if (!isPortrait)
                            onPortraitRotation();
                    }
                    else // Device is flipped
                    if (orientation > 45 && orientation < 145)
                    {
                        if (!isFlip)
                            onFlipRotation();
                    }
                    else // Device is in landscape
                    {
                        if (isPortrait)
                            onLandscapeRotation();
                    }
                }
            };

            // If device is capable for detecting orientation register listener
            if (orientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation())
                orientationEventListener.enable();
        }

    private void onPortraitRotation()
    {
        isPortrait = true;
        isFlip = false;
    }

    private void onFlipRotation()
    {
        isFlip = true;
        isPortrait = false;
    }

    private void onLandscapeRotation()
    {
        isPortrait = false;
        isFlip = false;
    }

    // Creates your custom dialog
    private void showCustomDialog()
    {
        MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(ActivityMain.this, isPortrait, isFlipped);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Now we know the orientation of our device, now create the dialog.

**NOTE** Use DialogFragment with a static constructor: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html (however, I am using simple Dialog for demonstration)

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog
{
    private boolean isPortrait;
    private boolean isFlipped;

    public MyDialog(Context context, boolean isPortrait, boolean isFlipped)
    {
        super(context);

        this.isPortrait = isPortrait;
        this.isFlipped = isFlipped;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Device is in landscape mode
        if (!isPortrait && !isFlipped)
            setContentView(R.layout.dialog_landscape);
        else
        if (isPortrait && !isFlipped) // Device is in portrait
            setContentView(R.layout.dialog_vertical);
        else // Device is flipped
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.dialog_landscape);

            // Rotate the entire root layout
            View layout = findViewById(R.id.rlContainer);

            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(layout, "rotation", 180).setDuration(0).start();
        }
    }
}
```

For rotation use NindeOldAndroids library.

**NOTE:** This solution is working for: landscape, portrait and flipped landscape. To show flipped portrait you must calculate the orientation in the orientation detect listener.

**NOTE 2:** Do not use system buttons! They are attached to the dialog which is attached to the parent (activity) locked orientation. Use layout-built-in button views.

Answer (score 0):

I think [cosic's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578828/how-to-force-rotate-dialog-fragment/24579595#24579595) is the best, along with this Activity configuration:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

...then in your Activity you can implement [onConfigurationChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)), and either ignore the change or do something custom.